# Multidim json array javascript, how to grab values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this data response from an AJAX call:

```
{"18:00":{"twopersons":1,"fourpersons":0}}
```

Which gets stored into a variable by `statsarray = data;`

Now how can i loop through statsarray and output the `twopersons` value?

So I can alert:

```
18:00 - There's 2 x 2persons and 0 x 4persons
```

Here is the Ajax call:

```
var statsarray;
var currentloopeddate = test_date.toString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$.post("/home/sessions",
    { action: 'partner_calendar_checkseats', date: currentloopeddate },
    function(data) { statsarray = data; }
);
```

Comment: Loop `statsarray`? or rather access `twopersons`?

Comment: You have a pretty good reputation. Have you tried something?

Comment: Please provide the code that makes the Ajax call and show how the variable `data` is initialized.

Comment: @JohnWatts Updated with ajax call

Comment: The success callback is only called if the request succeeds. I'm guessing it failed. Try adding an `error()`callback for debugging.

Comment: @JohnWatts I think it success since I do get an correct response?, and error does not give me anything.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I do get an correct response". I can see what is incorrect about it (`statsarray` is not assigned). I can't see anything about it that is correct. We can easily tell if the success callback is being called by adding an `alert` into it. Would you try that?

Answer (score 2):

Just do the following:

```
var twopersons = data["18:00"].twopersons;
var fourpersons = data["18:00"]["fourpersons"];
```

(Both variants are possible)

A variant would be:

```
var shorter = data["18:00"];
var twopersons = data.twopersons;
// ...
```

Comment: Didn't workout Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '18:00' of undefined

Comment: Updated question with ajax call

Comment: Then replace response with data, of course you cannot simply use copy and paste...

Comment: No ofcourse I have not just copy paste. I think its my statsarray that doesnt get set with the data from ajax call response, but I cant see where it goes wrong?

Comment: @Karem see my answer (the last updated part) because that may be the reason why your variable is undefined when you try to use it.

Comment: Well, after calling your function callback, statsarray should contain the correct data. But I cant see in your code how you continue using it. That would be helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
var tst = {"18:00":{"twopersons":1,"fourpersons":0}};
for(k in tst) {
  for(var z in tst[k]) {
   console.log(k + ": Theres "+tst[k][z] + " X " + z);
  }
}
```

Comment: No need for *minification* ;)

Comment: I would add `.hasOwnProperty` checks to make sure it won't break with libraries that extend `Object.prototype` (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

(**UPDATE: better example**)

```
var statsarray = {"18:00":{"twopersons":1,"fourpersons":0}};

var hour, persons, line, array;
for (hour in statsarray) {
    if (statsarray.hasOwnProperty(hour)) {
        array = [];
        for (persons in statsarray[hour]) {
            if (statsarray[hour].hasOwnProperty(persons)) {
                array.push(statsarray[hour][persons] + " x " + persons);
            }
        }
        line = hour + " - There's " + array.join(' and ');
        alert(line);
    }
}
```

See: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CPTZQ/2/).

Unfortunately you have to test with `.hasOwnProperty` to make sure it will work with some libraries.

**UPDATE:** You have added the code from your AJAX call in your question and I noticed that you declare the `statsarray` variable **outside** the callback function, but assign some value to that variable **inside** the callback. Just keep in mind that you have to run your iteration code **inside** the function that is the AJAX callback, where you have: `statsarray = data;` - just after this line, to make sure that you actually have some values to iterate over.